# Why is my foreign key not working when migrating - Laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

I am trying to do a fresh database migration in Laravel but it seems to be stuck on creating a foreign key. It generates the following error.

```
errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
```

I found this post already [Laravel migration (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728909/laravel-migration-errno-150-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed) but I used bigIncrements with unsignedBigInteger so that should work right? And I also did exactly the same in a previous project and that worked just fine.

```
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.42 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (1.05 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0.65 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_10_23_110756_create_campaigns_table
```

It seems to be stuck on `$table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('games');` in the campaigns table, which is wierd because it does `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');` just fine? When I comment out the game_id foreign key it migrates all the tables just fine? Is it maybe because the games table has not been created? And how would I solve this?

**Games Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGamesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('games');
    }
}
```

**Campaign Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCampaignsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->longText('settings');
            $table->longText('preview_settings');
            $table->text("description")->nullable();
            $table->enum('type', ['desktop', 'appstore', 'facebook', 'messenger', 'playstore', 'mobile']);
            $table->enum('published', ['Draft', 'Ready', 'Live']);
            $table->datetime("start_time")->nullable();
            $table->datetime("end_time")->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('game_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('games');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('campaigns');
    }
}
```

**User Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because campaigns table created but games table not created yet.

Migrate works in order.

Look list , games migrate not show;

```
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.42 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (1.05 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0.65 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_10_23_110756_create_campaigns_table
```

Can you edit and try the codes in this way ;

**Games Migration ;**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGamesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    Schema::table('campaigns', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('games');
    });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('games');
    }
}
```

**Campaign Migration ;**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCampaignsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->longText('settings');
            $table->longText('preview_settings');
            $table->text("description")->nullable();
            $table->enum('type', ['desktop', 'appstore', 'facebook', 'messenger', 'playstore', 'mobile']);
            $table->enum('published', ['Draft', 'Ready', 'Live']);
            $table->datetime("start_time")->nullable();
            $table->datetime("end_time")->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('game_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('campaigns');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that really a readable way to fix it tho? Can it be done in a way that enables me to have a seperate migration file for campaigns?

Comment: You can make firstly design database schema. This would be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->bigInteger('game_id')->unsigned();
```