# Laravel migration (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") - Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a products table and a product_exchanges table that has references products.id as a foreign. However, when I run the Laravel migration I got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `test`.`product_exchanges` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `product_exchanges` add constraint `product_exchanges_product_id_foreign` foreign key (`product_id`) references `products` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)
```

product table

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->text('name');   
    $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

products_exchanes table

```
Schema::create('product_exchanges', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->dateTime('date');
    $table->double('amount')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('count_from')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('count_to')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and I already put the products table before the product_exchanges table
[image]

[image]

I also made new two tables that look like this relation and get the same error

Comment: John Lobo's answer should do the trick, but additionally i would recommend to use `$table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained('products')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();`

instead, so laravel will automatically handle the fields type (in your case unsigned big integer) for you.

Comment: still get the same error after doing this

Comment: Interesting, works on my machine with the code you provided, did you remove both lines (the `    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');` AND the `    $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();` Line after adding mine?
` Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel migration (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728909/laravel-migration-errno-150-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed)

Comment: no this didn't work for me still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, I think it's because you wrote

```
    $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
```

try to change it to

```
Schema::create('product_exchanges', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->dateTime('date');
    $table->double('amount')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('count_from')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('count_to')->unsigned();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

or other solution is to change the id inside `products` table to be like this

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->text('name');   
    $table->boolean('active')->default(1);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and the other table still the same.

Let me know if this helps you.